# Creating dropdown at runtime and bind dropdown values after that - not working ngOptions

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am generating dropdown at runtime using AngularJs. I also want to bind corresponding options with it which will be generated based on dropdown type being created.

```
<div class="form-group" ng-repeat="attrib in col1Attribs">
    <label class="control-label" for="txtCode">{{attrib.displayText}}</label>
    <select class="form-control" 
         ng-options="item.configValue for item in configOptions(attrib.configType)" />
</div>
```

My controller has following method.

```
$scope.configOptions = function (type){
    return SmartCache.get(type); //SmartCache is my cacheFactory
}
```

**EDIT:**

Here is my data when parameter **type = 'Status'**

```
[{"$id":"1","people":[],"configId":"STAT001","configValue":"Active","startDate":"2014-01-31T00:00:00","endDate":"9999-01-01T00:00:00","description":"Active","status":1,"parentId":null,"isSelectable":true,"timestamp":"AAAAAAAAKHM=","isSystemData":true,"children":[],"parent":null,"personAttributes":[],"items1":[]},{"$id":"2","people":[],"configId":"STAT002","configValue":"Suspended","startDate":"2014-01-31T00:00:00","endDate":"9999-01-01T00:00:00","description":"Suspended","status":1,"parentId":null,"isSelectable":true,"timestamp":"AAAAAAAAKHQ=","isSystemData":true,"children":[],"parent":null,"personAttributes":[],"items1":[]},{"$id":"3","people":[],"configId":"STAT003","configValue":"Terminated","startDate":"2014-01-31T00:00:00","endDate":"9999-01-01T00:00:00","description":"Terminated","status":1,"parentId":null,"isSelectable":true,"timestamp":"AAAAAAAAKHU=","isSystemData":true,"children":[],"parent":null,"personAttributes":[],"items1":[]},{"$id":"4","people":[],"configId":"STAT004","configValue":"Deleted","startDate":"2014-01-31T00:00:00","endDate":"9999-01-01T00:00:00","description":"Deleted","status":1,"parentId":null,"isSelectable":true,"timestamp":"AAAAAAAAKHY=","isSystemData":true,"children":[],"parent":null,"personAttributes":[],"items1":[]}]
```

I am able to achieve my task using code below but not using ngOptions.

```
<div class="form-group" ng-repeat="attrib in col1Attribs">
        <label class="control-label" for="txtCode">{{attrib.displayText}}</label>
        <select class="form-control">
        <option ng-repeat="c in configOptions(attrib.configType)" value="{{c.configId}}">
           {{c.configValue}}</option>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Try this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1qpr165r/5/)**

Comment: what does the data look like in the SmartCache?

Comment: SmartCache has a key value pair i.e. `SmartCache.put("Status",myJsonObject)`

Comment: I guess you want to create multiple dropdown based on Type?

Comment: @Innovation: multiple drowndown are being created using `col1Attribs`. I want to bind these dropdown based on dropdown type.

Comment: what is e.name in this.Provided data does not contain name

Comment: Changed e to item for better clarity.

Comment: Try this:     <div ng-init = "data = configOptions(attrib.name)"></div> <select ng-model="data" ng-options="e.description for e in data">

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the rest of your code. Here is a snippet of how to create the dropdown:

```
 <select data-ng-options="e.description for e in configOptions" data-ng-model="selectedOption" />
```

Demo:http://plnkr.co/edit/YcuqZ1gs4iDAAgfLrZPO?p=preview

Comment: This binding will work when data data is static. However in my case this configOption need a parameter based on which data will be binded to a dropdown

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are trying this

Use `as`

```
<select class="form-control" 
         ng-options="item.configId as item.configValue for item in configOptions(attrib.configType)" />
```

`configId` adds as option value and `configValue` as display value.

Comment: Can you post a plnkr.co/edit or jsfiddle.com of what you tried?

Comment: Fiddle added, please look